# React doesn't change list correctly when order of elements change

Tags: reactjs, react-native-maps

I have a list below.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Marker } from 'react-native-maps';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { selectPin } from '../reducers/pinReducer';

const Markers = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const pinsAvailable = useSelector(state => state.pin.allTheAvailablePins);

    return (
        <>
            {pinsAvailable.map((pin, index) => {
                console.log(index === 0) // returns true when index is 0
                return <Marker 
                key={pin.id} 
                coordinate={pin.coords}
                pinColor={index === 0 ? "red" : "green"} // but it doesnt work here...
                onPress={() => dispatch(selectPin({pin}))} />
            })}
        </>
    )
}

export default Markers;
```

At first, `pinsAvailable` variable gets array of `pin` objects. And it is rendered fine at first. When the list changes (List doesn't get new elements or there is not something deleted, only order of the list changes.) it doesn't work like how I want.

The issue is, at the first render, it renders first element of lists `pinColor` property as `"red"` and rest is rendered as `"green"`. But after first render it renders every elements `pinColor` as `"green"`.

What I want is knowing why lists first element only renders `pinColor` property as `"red"` at first render and why not in other renders. In fact `index === 0` returns true. The only thing changes in list is nothing but "order of elements".

EDIT;

I call fetchRoute from somewhere in my code.

```
export const fetchRoute = async (dispatch, location) => {
    if(location){
        const res = await axios.get(`http://192.168.1.98:3000/api/sevkiyat/rotayiciz?lat=${location.latitude}&lon=${location.longitude}`);
        dispatch(setAllThePinsAvailable({pins: res.data.orderedDeliveries})); // orderedDeliveries is array of reordered pins.
        dispatch(setRoutePath({routePath: res.data.lines}));
    }
}
```

Below code is a Redux Toolkit slice.

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const initialState = {
    selectedPin: null,
    deliveryToBeArrived: null,
    allTheAvailablePins: [],
    fetchPinsLoading: true,
    fetchPinsError: null,
}

export const pinSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'pin',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        unselectPin: (state) => {
            state.selectedPin = null;
        },
        selectPin: (state, action) => {
            state.selectedPin = action.payload.pin;
        },
        startDeliveryToBeArrived: (state, action) => {
            state.deliveryToBeArrived = action.payload.delivery;
        },
        abortDeliveryToBeArrived: (state) => {
            state.deliveryToBeArrived = null;
        },
        setAllThePinsAvailable: (state, action) => {
            state.allTheAvailablePins = action.payload.pins;
            state.fetchPinsLoading = false;
        },
        setFetchPinsError: (state, action) => {
            state.fetchPinsError = action.payload.error;
        }
    },
})

export const { setAllThePinsAvailable, selectPin, unselectPin, startDeliveryToBeArrived } = pinSlice.actions

export default pinSlice.reducer;
```

Below code is main store.

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import locationReducer from '../reducers/locationReducer';
import modalReducer from '../reducers/modalReducer';
import pinReducer from '../reducers/pinReducer';
import routeReducer from '../reducers/routeReducer';
import sampleReducer from '../reducers/sampleReducer'

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        sample: sampleReducer,
        pin: pinReducer,
        location: locationReducer,
        modal: modalReducer,
        route: routeReducer,
    },
    middleware: getDefaultMiddleware => getDefaultMiddleware({
        serializableCheck: false
    })
})
```

AN EDIT MORE: It is fixed when I give hex color instead of color name to `pinColor`. The problems source comes from react-native-maps library.

Comment: How are you changing the order of the array elements? Can you edit your question to show us what is happening to the `pinsAvailable` array?

Comment: @DrewReese I edited as you wanted.

Comment: @DrewReese It gets array from server, basically.

Comment: Yeah, I see that, thank you. I just wanted to ensure it wasn't something silly like `array.sort`. I also just noticed in your snippet you don't return the `Marker` in the mapping, not sure if that's just a copy/paste typo or not. Is `Marker` doing any sort of caching/memoization on the props? Can we see that `Marker` component? Outside this I don't see any overt issues. Are the `pin.id`'s consistent between reorderings?

Comment: @DrewReese I returned Marker in list, I just forget to put it this question, sorry. pin.id's are unique. Marker component is from a package react-native-maps.

Comment: Do you have a running example or can you create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces this issue that we can inspect and debug live?

Comment: @DrewReese It is a React Native app, I don't know if it can be run in codesandbox. :/

Comment: We need a [mcve] to help you answer this question. No need to run your full app, just the code needed to reproduce your bug.

Comment: No worries, try an [Expo snack](https://expo.dev/) then. And yes, you need only create a minimal example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: It seems react-native-maps has many quirks, and this might be one of them. You might get answers at their GitHub issue tracker.

Comment: It is fixed weirdly when I give hexcolor instead of color name, lmao. Thanks for your helps guys :) I would like to know why tbh, just for curiosity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fixed when I give hex color instead of color name to pinColor. The problems source comes from react-native-maps library.

For instance: `"#FF0000"` instead of `"red"`